# Retrofit 2 handling dynamic api callbacks of either JSONArray or JSONObject

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

My `JSON` server response is usually like this `[{}]` (Array of Objects) except that they set up the errors to return an Object `{}` So when I call of course if there is an issue with the response and it returns an object I get the following error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

In my code as I am expecting an `ArrayList` and getting an object (I am not sure how to handle this though?  When I get the object that means there is a problem with the API call and I need to deal with what is responded in the object.

Example Error response from API:

```
{
  "StatusCode": -7,
  "StatusMessage": "Invalid",
  "Details": ""
}
```

APIService Interface below:

```
interface MyAPIService {
    @GET("RequestByToken")
    fun getCurrentRequestAsync(
        @Query("token") token: String
    ): Deferred<List<CurrentResponse>>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(
            connectivityInterceptor: ConnectivityInterceptor
        ): MyAPIService {
            val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->

                //Creates a new URL adding in the CONST'S
                val url = chain.request()
                    .url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("format", FORMAT)
                    .build()

                //Creates new Request with the new URL
                val request = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .url(url.toString())
                    .build()

                println(request)
                return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
            }

            //Intercepts each http call and adds the url above automatically
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(MyAPIService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `Deferred<Any>` instead of `Deferred<List<CurrentResponse>>` it will accept all models in on response check if(response.body is List){//it mean its your array} else { //it is error response

Comment: The issue I run into with returning Any is that when I need to use the List<CurrentResponse> and set it with as List<CurrentResponse> it complains that it cant convert it from LinkedTreeMap?

Comment: this error return in onFailure method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonElement` as your return type and determine if it is a `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` by using the method `isJsonArray()`, and from there, you can simply deserialize it.

You can also do this in a general way, and create a class that represents both of your list and object responses, and write a type adapter for that type:

```
 sealed class SampleResponse {
    data class ArraySampleResponse(val currentResponses: List<CurrentResponse>) : SampleResponse()
    data class SimpleSampleResponse(val currentResponse: CurrentResponse) : SampleResponse()
}
class CustomDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<SampleResponse> {

    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): SampleResponse {
        if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            // parse as object and create your object
            return SampleResponse.SimpleSampleResponse() 
        } else if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            // parse as array and create your object
            return SampleResponse.ArraySampleResponse()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer.

Comment: What it does is, it creates a decerializer for a custom class (SampleResponse) -which is yours- and can create that class based on the data that is received via the network. You would declare your API as `Deferred<SampleResponse>`, and add this serializer to Gson, and it will be created based on what the root json element is - an array or an object- (or any other condition that you may like).
You need to create the SampleResponse class to your likings to have multiple fields for when it is initiated with list or an object. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Very helpful however I am running into issues as I am using Kotlin and this looks like Java

I have this so far
```
class CustomDeserializer(): JsonDeserializer<SampleResponse> {
    
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): SampleResponse {
        if (json.isJsonObject) {
            // parse as object and create your object
        } else if (json.isJsonArray) {
            // parse as array and create your object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Converting the code above to Kotlin should do no harm! :)

Comment: Well the issue I am running into is it does not know what SampleResponse is

Comment: You need to create the SampleResponse class yourself.

Comment: OK that makes sense but what goes into that class?  also I thought that was the point of 
`.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`
so that I wouldn't have to do this?

Comment: I've edited my code further using sealed classes. Please note that `Sample` is just a place holder and it is better to be renamed after what it is used for in your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191181/discussion-between-crash1hd-and-adib-faramarzi).

Comment: Is the problem solved? or my answer need anything to be complete?